# 403 redirect loop on every page

Tags: redirection

I'm not sure what is causing this, but every page of my Drupal site is throwing a 403 error redirect loop.

I was just working on the project this morning, and left and came back to it and can't figure out what has gone wrong.

If anyone could event point me toward a resource for figuring out what has gone wrong it would be a huge help.

Comment: Please tell more about you you have, is there any special module you install? write new thing in new custom module?

Comment: as said before, if there is any configuration done or code added by your side. Check this link https://www.drupal.org/node/873446#comment-3600396 in case you have same problem

Comment: I did set up a custom 403 page a while back. Is there a way I change that to the default in the database somewhere?

Comment: @Tyler what you add you your `template.php` for handle 403 ? I think your problem is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have wrongly configured 403 page, in order to change it back, you can override it by adding following on your settings.php

```
 $conf['site_403'] = '';
```